# Add project reference with specific version in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

Is it possible to add a version to the `ProjectReference` in VS 2017?

I've tried building like so: `<ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" Version="1.0.1.4" />`

But the version of that assembly falls back down to `1.0.1.3` after building.

Some additional info:

in the `.nuspec` file that gets generated on build, it contains a reference to the old version `<dependency id="Project2" version="1.0.1.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />` even though that is not the current version, and even if i edit the `.nuspec` manually, it goes back to `1.0.1.3` on the next build

Comment: why can't you set the version of the `Project2.csproj` to a higher version?

Comment: I did, but for some reason it gets packed into the nuget package as the older version. This is the nuget package that builds on project build

Comment: did you call `dotnet restore` after changing the versions? the package versions are calculated at restore time as part of the dependency graph

Comment: yes i did, i even tried manually changing the version in the `.nuspec` file in the obj folder, but then on build it just set the version back to the old one

Comment: Wow, you know what? I just did a dotnet restore and it fixed it.. I can't believe i thought i did that but never actually did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinUllrich for pointing out that i need to run a `dotnet restore`. I somehow thought i had done that but that was the culprit the whole time.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.